# How to create a RGB gradient?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I would like to know how to create a perfect RGB gradient in Illustrator like this:

[image]

Edit: I tried to use the gradient tool, but how to place the colors correct?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt so far and explain why it needs improvement?

Comment: @JohnB this is an example image from the web to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: Shows no effort. What have you tried? Why is it not working? John *did* ask... you skirted the question. My down vote is *not* personal. This is just a poor question due to the lack of effort displayed.

Comment: Simple "how-tos" are *not* okay here. It's been discussed. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/614/should-we-consider-how-to-visually-represent-questions-on-topic You need to at least show *some* effort to solve the issue yourself. You knew when you posted this there was no actual effort behind it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown gradient consists of 5 full colors.

- `#ff0000` (red)
- `#ffff00` (yellow)
- `#00ff00` (green)
- `#00ffff` (cyan)
- `#0000ff` (blue)

Use the gradient tool and setup the colors with an offset of 20% like this:

[image]

Comment: oddly, it skips magenta!